# How can I update each file in a ZIP archive?

Tags: c#, zip, system.io.compression, c#-ziparchive

When trying the following I get the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.". How can I loop through Zip entries and update them?

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(@"c:\file.zip",ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"c:\file.txt", entry.FullName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update a collection whilst enumerating through it.

You could convert to a for loop instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < archive.Entries.Count; i++)
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"c:\file.txt", archive.Entries[i].FullName);
}
```

You may find it helpful to have a read of the API reference on [Enumerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=netframework-4.7.1).

*"Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection."*